# Right way to Active Record DB modeling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, modeling

If I use STI, I'll have several nil columns on my DB and I don't know if I can use Polymorphic Associations in cases like that. Any tip or some references?

[!How the right way to modeling somethink like that?] [1][1]

Comment: Why do you have nil columns? For which of the models in the image do you consider STI or Polymorphoc Associations?

Comment: Cause if I create a main class with all attributes, theres a child classes that doesn't needs all attributes, then in that classes, these attributes will be nil.

Comment: But looking at your datamodel both junior and senior have the exact same attributes. What columns do you expect to be nil?

Comment: Im talking about classes before junior and senior. The classe Employee(junior and senior) in not a problem. The problem is the classes before that contains the same attributes and one more. How I design that classes without repeat the same attributes in all that? For example, classes Lider and Coordenador have the same attributes and one more.

Answer (score 1):

Though I don't understand the language completely from the image. If I understand I think one Coordinator has many Junior employee and senior employee. And seems like both employee table has the same type of column. What I would do in this case is, I would just create one employee table and keep a enum column of role. The model would look something like below-

```
class Coordinator
 has_many: :employees
end

class Employee
 belongs_to: :coordinator

 enum role: { junior: 0, senior: 1 }
end
```

If you haven't used enum in Rails yet, it's really handy. [Take a look](https://naturaily.com/blog/ruby-on-rails-enum)

Comment: The problem is not Cordinator class, its ok. The problem is with the classes before that contains the same attributes with one or two more. How can I design it without repeat all attributes in every class?